# Default DB values during inserting new record to QSqlTableModel

Tags: qt, qsqltablemodel

How to insert new record to QSqlTableModel with respect to default values of DB?
UPD:
I am trying to call `pTableModel->insertRecord(0, pTableModel->record(0));`
or `pTableModel->insertRecord(0, pTableModel->record());`
or `pTableModel->insertRecord(QSqlDatabase::database().record("tableName"));`
or `pTableModel->insertRow(0);`

Result the same, all fields are NULL instead of default values of DB.

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Is this a QT question or a database question? We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you're inserting at row 0 may be an issue.  When I've tried doing that, I don't get the record I expect when I later ask for the record at row 1 (which is where the inserted record *should* be after a call of `insertRecord(0, ...)`).  Also, are you calling `pTableModel->submit()` or `pTableModel->submitAll()`?  If not, your record never gets committed to the database.

This code works for me:

```
QSqlRecord  rec( pTableModel->record() );

// Insert at end of table
pTableModel->insertRecord( -1, rec );
pTableModel->submitAll(); 
// Or, pTableModel->submit(), depending on the model's edit strategy

// Grab the last row.  It should be the one just inserted.
QSqlRecord  writtenRec( pTableModel->record( pTableModel->rowCount() - 1 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, now I don't use this idea for some reasons.
But my idea was to get default DB values for a record without submitting of new record to the DB. But it seems that this impossible without writing additional code :)